# "Database connection error" when installing 1.7.0.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, error, install

I'm installing Magento version 1.7.0.2 on an Ubuntu VM, hosted in Azure - **I'm getting "Database connection error" in the Magento Installation Wizard.**

I've installed PHP & MySQL as instructed [here](http://ossonazure.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-magento-on-windows-azure).
In mysql, I've granted access to a userx, which is the same one entered in the wizard.

Other threads suggested (and I tried):

- Replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" - didn't help
- Installing "InnoDB" - Mysql says it is default

EDIT - These are the modules I've installed:
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-mcrypt php5-gd php5-common
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server

Answer (score 1):

What version of MySQL are you running? In 5.6 the `have_innodb` check is no longer working and could cause the connection failure. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/202 for details.

Comment: I'm using 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1.

Comment: Do you have the php-pdo and php-mysql loaded?

Comment: See my edit. Is php-pdo mandatory?

Comment: @seldary Yes, it is. See this for a full list of system requirements: http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements